# How to specify the binary location of selenium with an unc path?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = 'c://c/chrome/chrome.exe'  # works as intended 
# chrome_options.binary_location = '//localhost/c/chrome/chrome.exe' #didn't work ,no error shown up ,chromium just crashed 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'//localhost/c/chrome/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://passport.5173.com')
```

This is what I've tried ,the real path works ,but when I passed the unc path instead ,chrome crashed .I use portable chromium version 83 .

Comment: What error do you see? Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB No error shown up,chrome was opened ,and then it just crashed .

Comment: @DebanjanB I was using portable chromium .